# How do you know if the HTTP compression is working?

Tags: http, iis-7, compression

How do you know if the HTTP compression setup is working? Is there any tool I can use to see the compressed page before it is uncompressed by the browser? Are there any tools to measure the amount compressed and response speed?

Answer (score 22):

This isn't IIS-specific, but you can use cURL:

```
curl -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate' -D - http://example.com
```

Then look for a `Content-Encoding: gzip` header in the output.

Comment: Much easier than the other answers.

Comment: didn't work for me altough chrome is showing in header response

Answer (score 15):

For Windows, I highly recommend [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), which is a client-side tool that proxies your web traffic and lets you examine it.  It will show you if compression is on and working.  It is also useful for many other client-side HTTP-related debugging and diagnosis tasks.

Comment: I don't think it acts a proxy; I thought it tapped into the TCP/IP stack and <a href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997537.aspx">hooked</a> into transmissions. No?

Comment: Yeah, it's a proxy.  As long as the browser is well behaved and follows the usual mechanisms to determine what proxy to use, no special hooking is required.

Answer (score 13):

If you have chrome, press F12 and then navigate to the site. Once the site loads, go the Network tab.  Click on the file you are looking and the then Look for section Response Headers under Headers. Look for content-encoding section

Look at the picture below for a example

[image]

To see how much data is transferred, in the network tab, hover over with mouse over the size column. It shows the full file size as well the size of data transferred over network. An example below. See the tool-tip that shows this info

[image: Data transfer size]

Comment: The `content-encoding:gzip` simply shows that gzip is working. But where do you see the data Size and content size, that will help determine compression ratio etc?

Comment: Updated the answer with this info

Answer (score 9):

As well as something like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/) to look at the HTTP-level traffic, you can use Firefox with the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) add-ons. YSlow gives you a lot of useful analysis about why your page might be slow - among these, it gives you the size of the various assets that your request downloads (HTML, CSS, JavaScript, images and other media etc). You can compare the size of pages with and without compression - if the HTML is smaller with the compression turned on, you know it's working. It will also give you values with an empty cache and a primed cache, allowing you to see how much you're saving for both new visitors and returning visitors.

Comment: Another vote for YSlow here. It will warn you if any of your assets aren't gzipped.

Answer (score 8):

You can use this website:
http://whatsmyip.org/mod_gzip_test/

Answer (score 8):

[Wireshark, former Etherial](http://www.wireshark.org/) has proved to be the most valuable tool for me.
Just choose a network adapter (if there are many), type "tcp port 80" into the filter field, press Capture - and you're all set.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest, quickest thing is to take a look at the Developer Tools *Network* tab and see if the *Content* and *Size* values for each request are different. If the values differ, then compression is working. Divide *size* by *content* to get your compression ratio. I'm not sure how long these values have been visible, but they're there in Chrome 53. Not sure on Firefox.

[image: Chrome Developer Tools, Network tab]

Comment: This is the right answer. Please note, in latest version of chrome, the `Content` field shown above is not visible by default. Also I think it's been renamed to `Content-Length`. If it's not visible, right-click on the column headers anywhere, and select `Response-Headers` it from the list of fields and then select `Content-Length` in order to see it.

Answer (score 4):

For Firefox have a look at these add-ons:

1. Firebug
2. HttpFox

Both can be used to monitor your traffic to/from the browser (You can see the size of each response). I especially like Httpfox, a really nice add-on I use everyday.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) to spy on your HTTP transmissions.

"Build Request" (create an HTTP GET) and check the "Content-Encoding" header of the HTTP response for your uncompressed page, and check its "Content-Length". Compare those to the same values for your compressed page.

"Content-Encoding" should be something like "gzip" for compressed responses, and your "Content-Length" should be shorter. You can use the "Content-Length" fields from both to determine the compression ratio.

Answer (score 2):

In the Chrome Developer Tools, You can add the response header of your choice—`content-encoding` in your case—in the columns of the <kbd>Network</kbd> tab.

Simply right click on a request, then click <kbd>Header Options</kbd>, <kbd>Response Headers</kbd>, and then select <kbd>Content-Encoding</kbd>.

Once you've done that, you'll be able to see the `content-encoding` in the <kbd>Network</kbd> tab without needing to click on any individual request:

[image: Example]

Comment: Not sure why this doesn't have more up-votes. It is a great answer. Using this technique, you can find that maybe your html is zipped, but that your json isn't.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go really low tech, you can telnet to the HTTP port (80?) on the target server and type in the request manually. If you get plain text back, then it's not gzipped, but if you get gibberish then you're onto something. If you need to see the structure of the headers, you can copy them from Firefox using something like the [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) extension.

Comment: I don't think this will work sk, unless you type in the correct compression headers.  Usually the browser sends headers to the server first indicating the types of compression it will accept, and the server should then only send content in a compression format that is supported by the browser (or otherwise plain uncompressed).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use this:

http://www.whatsmyip.org/http-compression-test/

Comment: also see http://99webtools.com/http_compression.php# - this checks if browser supports it too

Answer (score -2):

We searched around a bit. Apparently, there are a lot of sites which can verify that our pages are compressed.

Comment: Yeah, there are some good sites that do this, but they're not very helpful for intranet servers or localhost development. :-(